# PHPMyAdmin - set global user and password for multiple databases

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, config

I would like do my support database. I have in config.inc.php file information to login to my databases (hosts, logins, passwords).

But I would like set global user for all defined databases. So I write global login and password and can manage all my defined database. But I don't know how do it?

This is fragment my config.inc.php:

```
/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/* Authentication type */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'global user';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password global user\'s'; // use here your password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
/* Server parameters */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'host.frist.database';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'information_schema';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'user.frist.bazy';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password.frist.database';

$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'host.second.database';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'information_schema';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'user.second.bazy';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password.second.database';
```

I haven't idea, how do it...

Comment: So you have username and password for user with access to all databases and you don't know where to put them in this config file? Or you don't know how to create such user in the first place?

Comment: I know how add information about login to config file, but I would like set, that I login with global user (no with user database) to PHPMyAdmin and after I have list with my all databases, who I added to config file. I config file on top I add global user and after are my databases.

Comment: Sorry but I really do not understand what are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: Ok, other example. I have 5 databases (host for frist database: `db383695447.db.1and1.com`, `login` and `password`, for other 4 similar but host is difrent). When I write to config file data ($cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'];...['login'];...['password'];...['auth_type'] = 'config') and after go to PHPMyAdmin I see all databases, but other person, when go to this same address also see my all databases and can make changes. I would like set one login and password for all phpmyadmin, so I don't must login individually to databases, because I saved passwords in config file. You understand? :-)

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand. You want to login to phmyadmin interface, not any existing mysql server, have listed all configured connections and quickly switch between them, without providing any other passwords. I'm afraid it's not possible, since it's not how phpmyadmin works.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So, I must remake phpmyadmin. But, if any person have idea - I wait for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Yust store your "Global" config in a separate array and use this as default for each server e.g. like this:

```
$global['user'] = 'global user';
$global['password'] = 'password global user\'s'; // use here your password
$global['auth_type'] = 'config';
$global['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;


$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i] = $global;
/* individual config for first server */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'host.frist.database';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'user.frist.bazy';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password.frist.database';


$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i] = $global;
/* individual config for second server */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'host.second.database';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'user.second.bazy';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password.second.database';
```